# uMatrix blocked content in Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, umatrix

When blocking content like YouTube videos with uMatrix it looks normally like this in Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

but now I have seen a video, where it looks like that in Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome]

That makes more sense for me because it shows much better blocked content and the specific domain. I would like to know if this behavior is really because of Firefox/Chrome, or if it depends on the uMatrix addon and its version? I would have expected that the graphics for blocked contents is provided by the addon and not by the browser itself. Why should the browser that does not block content by itself provide blocked element graphics?

Comment: What do you mean by "but now I have seen a video"?

Comment: its not important how I spotted that, just important that its different in the browsers